# Return to a previous version - Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-console

I am looking to go back to the previous version of my site how can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mouse over the old deployment, to the right you'll see three dots. Click that for a dropdown menu... Choose the "Rollback" option.

[image: The three dots]

[image: The dropdown menu]